# Vercel hosted error, Error: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /var/task/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libpng16.so.16)

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, module, vercel

```
Error: /lib64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found 
(required by /var/task/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libpng16.so.16)
```

This is the error i am getting. The app works fine on localhost and it has worked fine until i  installed color thief. I wonder what could be the cause of this error.

I tried googling the error and asking chatgpt, i went in vercel document but couldnt find the reason.